# EventHandler for ImapClient(Outlook.office365.com) don't work, but it works with Imap.gmail.com

Tags: c#, email

I have the following code:

```
private void StartReceiving()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, "MY Gmail", "MyPAssword", AuthMethod.Login, true))
        using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient("Outlook.office365.com", 993, "support@mydomain.dk", "MyPAssword", AuthMethod.Login, true))
        {
            if (client.Supports("IDLE") == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Server does not support IMAP IDLE");
                return;
            }

            IEnumerable<uint> uids = client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());
            IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages = client.GetMessages(uids);

            client.NewMessage += new EventHandler<IdleMessageEventArgs>(OnNewMessage);
            while (true) ;
        }
    });
}

static void OnNewMessage(object sender, IdleMessageEventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage m = e.Client.GetMessage(e.MessageUID, FetchOptions.Normal);
    f.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        f.txtMessage.AppendText("-------------------------------------" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yy HH:mm") + " \n " +
            "From: " + m.From + "\n");
        UpdateList(m);
    });
}
```

If i use the `gmail` option, everything works just fine. But if I use the `Outlook.office365.com` I never get into `OnNewMessage` when i receive an email.

Do anyone have any idea about why this dont work.?

Comment: Does the `MessageBox` show in either case?

Comment: @mjwills Nope, I dont get any errors. and if both have unread mails i can see them in `uids `